# error encountered when processing the current DDL statement in pluggable database ORAPDB1: the tablespace 'INTERVENTION_TBS' does no exist

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I am using oracle 12c and I'm having a little trouble trying to attribute tablespace to a user.

Here is the error I got when processing the current DDL statement in pluggable database ORAPDB1:

> the tablespace 'INTERVENTION_TBS' does no exist

Note that the tablespace was created successfully. So could someone suggest a solution please?

For more details I used this syntax query

```
CREATE USER c##DBAINTERVENTION 
    Identified by interventiondb 
    Default Tablespace INTERVENTION_TBS 
    Temporary Tablespace INTERVENTION_TempTBS;
```

Comment: you are creating a global user, that means the tablespace has to exist in **all** pluggable databases.

Comment: And  what's the solution for that please?

Answer (score 9):

run the following statements:

```
alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=TRUE;

ALTER USER [username] IDENTIFIED BY [password];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create a common user which will have access to all the PDBs in a CDB. As the user has access to all PDBs it can also create an object on those PDBs hence we need tablespace to create the objects. This is the reason why you need to have the tablespace specified in the `CREATE USER` command on all PDBs.

Please verify that you the  `INTERVENTION_TBS` tablespace exists on all PDBs using the following query.

```
select cp.pdb_name 
from cdb_pdbs cp join v$tablespace tb on(cp.con_id=tb.con_id) 
where tb.name='INTERVENTION_TBS';
```

This query list all the PDBs which has the tablespace. If this tablespace doesn't exist on one of your PDBs then create one.

Comment: how to create the tablespace in the PDBs? the above query returns "no rows selected"

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue, the solution for me was to create the user with a default profile and container = all.

```
CREATE USER c##DBAINTERVENTION 
    Identified by interventiondb 
    Default Tablespace INTERVENTION_TBS 
    Temporary Tablespace INTERVENTION_TempTBS
    PROFILE DEFAULT
    ACCOUNT UNLOCK container = all;
```